# Align Text from multiline textbox for printing in vb6

Tags: visual-studio, printing, vb6, textbox, cmd

I currently have this

> > Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
> >
> > Dim i As Long
> >
> > Printer.FontItalic = True
> >
> > Printer.CurrentX = 850
> >
> > Printer.FontSize = 20
> >
> > Printer.ForeColor = RGB(255, 102, 102)
> >
> > Printer.Print txtR.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & GTB3.Text
> >
> > Printer.EndDoc
> >     End Sub

---

But I want to insert somewhere in there some code that will align all the text that is printed from the two text boxes into the center

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

This could set it to the left margin

```
Printer.CurrentX = LeftMargin
```

so something possibly similar to the below code should help you center it.

```
Printer.CurrentX = LeftMargin + _
       (PrintWidth - Printer.TextWidth(str)) / 2
```